# Problema ao imprimir um relatório utilizando ReportViewer

Tags: c#, asp.net

## Problema

Possuo diversos relatórios *Report Services Client* que quando vou tentar imprimir acontece 2 possíveis erros:

1. Se não estiver instalado o *rsclientprint.dll* aparece a seguinte mensagem quando tento imprimir o relatório: 
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
2. Se estiver instalado o *rsclientprint.dll* e a data de modificação dele for 2009 o navegador IE para de responder quando tento imprimir o relatório.
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Observações

1. Quando é instalado o *rsclientprint.dll* de 2010, funciona normalmente.
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
2. Não quero soluções como: `Permitir o Download de Active X habilitado` ou `Adicionar a página aos sites confiáveis do IE`.
3. No servidor funciona normalmente a impressão, o problema só ocorre quando tento imprimir remotamente de qualquer outra máquina.

Existe alguma outra maneira de eu fazer funcionar a impressão sem o rsclientprint.dll? Ou é possível controlar para ele sempre instalar o de `2010`?

Comment: Pelas informações que você mostrou, o erro tá na linkagem da dll mesmo (por isso o erro de execução). Só fiquei na dúvida: qual o problema de usar o de 2010?

Comment: O componente é instalado automaticamente pelo navegador, porém hora ele instala arquivos de 2009 e hora ele instala arquivos de 2010.. simplesmente aleatório. E quando fica instalado o de 2009 da problema. Fica inviável eu mandar os arquivos de 2010 e tentar ensinar todos meus usuários leigos (+ de 50) a como trocar os arquivos e o problema vai continuar com novos usuários.

Comment: Encontrei 2 links que pode ajudar a gerar um pacote de instalação: http://juliobattisti.com.br/tutoriais/herbertgois/programandocsharp025.asp e http://techne.cesar.org.br/gerando-um-pacote-de-instalacao-no-visual-studio-2008/

Answer (score 2):

Se você distribuir sua aplicação em um computador que não tem o Visual Studio instalado, você não pode assumir necessariamente que o controle ReportViewer esta disponível; mesmo depois de ter instalado a .NET Framework. Você pode contornar este problema efetuando o [download do Report Viewer Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=8a166cac-758d-45c8-b637-dd7726e61367)

Outra alternativa é construir um programa de Setup a partir do Visual Studio (Professional) para distribuir sua aplicação. Assim que for detectado que sua aplicação usa o ReportViewer o mesmo será incluído na distribuição da sua aplicação.

O VB Express e C# Express não incluem o controle `ReportViewer`. Isto significa que se você estiver usando o VB Express ou C# Express para desenvolver uma aplicação você precisa primeiro efetuar o download e a seguir instalar o *Report Viewer Redistributable* na sua máquina de desenvolvimento a fim de compilar junto com o projeto. Você precisa também instalar o *Report Viewer Redistributable* em toda a máquina de destino na qual você esta instalando a sua aplicação.

Comment: Antes de tudo eu uso o Visual Studio Professional, sabe me dizer como faço para criar esse Setup? E mesmo que meus usuários acessem pela web vai funcionar na máquina deles?

Comment: Depois de instalado o Redistributable vai funcionar sim. O link que está na resposta pode ser o suficiente se você instalar ele no computador de cada cliente.